# Почему в навигационной панели пропадает кнопка в iOS10?

Tags: ios, swift4, navigationbar

Кнопка создается вот так:

```
// FIXME: не работает в iOS 10 !!!

languageTopBarButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
languageTopBarButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "iconGlobe"), for: .normal)
languageTopBarButton.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
languageTopBarButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.green, for: .normal)
languageTopBarButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(rightNavButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)

let navBarHeight = navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.height
var rightButtonFrame = languageTopBarButton.frame
rightButtonFrame.size = CGSize(width: rightButtonFrame.width, height: navBarHeight!)
languageTopBarButton.frame = rightButtonFrame

let buttonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: languageTopBarButton)

navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = buttonItem
```

в iOS 11 с ней все в порядке, но в iOS 10 она не появляется:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что не так делаю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В iOS10, при создании кнопки этим кодом, ширина у фрейма кнопки остается неопределенной. Если добавить, например, sizeToFit(), после того как у кнопки проставлены свойства заголовка и изображения (либо проставить ширину вручную), ширина фрейма принимает актуальное значение и кнопку становится видно:

```
// ...
languageTopBarButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(rightNavButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)

languageTopBarButton.sizeToFit() // <-- добавим эту строку в код из вопроса

let navBarHeight = navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.height
// ...
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]